# Oracle regular expression replacement for negative lookahead/lookbehind that doesn't consume a character

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a better answer to a very similar problem to the post "Oracle regular expression replacement for negative lookahead/lookbehind"

My problem find numbers of exactly 8 digit coming after a keyword.

```
Must Match:
 REF12345678
 REF:12345678
 REF any text or short 23 num 12345678
```

```
But do NOT match:
REF 123456789
REF anything 123456789
```

```
'(REF)(.*?)(\d{8})(\W|$)'; # matches 9 digits: REF 123456789
'(REF)(.*?)\D(\d{8})(\W|$)'; # won't match REF12345678
```

\D was suggested as a solution in an existing post as a way to avoid .*? matching the 1st digit of 9, but if there are no non-digits left it won't work.  (In REF12345678 the F in REF was used already).

```
'(REF)(.*?)(?<!\d)(\d{8})(\W|$)'
```

works wonderfully in Perl, not Oracle, which doesn't support negative lookbehind.

How can I do a zero-width assertion either that a non-digit comes before the number, or the .* did not end with a digit?
(Using \D? won't work.)

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(REF)(.*?\D)?(\d{8})(\W|$)
```

This says, *if* there are any characters between `REF` and the eight digits, the last one must be a non-digit.